# could not run react-native project

Tags: react-native

I want to run sample app from react-native. I use react-native run-ios but it does not work. I get following error:

```
 ERROR  ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/noemiee/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache.noindex/J47OOOPSA8X3/modules.idx.lock'
{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"lstat","path":"/Users/noemiee/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache.noindex/J47OOOPSA8X3/modules.idx.lock"}
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/noemiee/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache.noindex/J47OOOPSA8X3/modules.idx.lock'
```

I'm not sure whether those files exist in the project, or the path is right. Could anyone help me to fix this error? Even when I follow the steps from react-native's website to create this project it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check do Node exist in your system or not.Once i have also experience this when i uninstalled my brew of my mac system.Same error was occurring ,then i installed node in my system and then go inside your project ,run npm install --save.it will work.